# Vue 3 <Component :is=""> somehow turns camelCase in to lowercase

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

In my app, users can define what social media platforms they want link to, and how those links should look on their page. For this I was trying to load the components that display the link to the social media platform dynamically. Every social media platfrom will have its own component that generates the link.

A simple example

```js
<script setup>
  import LinkToInstagram from './socialmedia/LinkToInstagram.vue'
  import LinkToFacebook  from './socialmedia/LinkToFacebook.vue'
  //This will be loaded through an API
  const links = [
    'Instagram',
    'Facebook'
  ]
</script>

<template>
  <span v-for="social in links" :set="currentComponent = 'LinkTo' + social">
    <component :is="currentComponent" show-link-text="true" slug="itest" />
  </span>
</template>

<style scoped>
</style>
```

I would expect that this would output something along the lines of:

```html
<LinkToInstagram show-link-text="true" slug="itest"></LinkToInstagram>
```

and Vue would load the right component.

Instate this outputs:

```
<linktoinstagram show-link-text="true" slug="itest"></linktoinstagram>
```

all lower case and nothing is loaded.

I tried making it kabab-case, no luck. I printed the varible `currentComponent` it displays exactly what it should:

`LinkToInstagram` (camelCase). This is how you use the  attribute right? or am I  missing the whole point here?

If I hardcode <LinkToInstagram ... /> then all works as expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you are importing components, you can simply use them as values:

```js
<script setup>
  import LinkToInstagram from './socialmedia/LinkToInstagram.vue'
  import LinkToFacebook  from './socialmedia/LinkToFacebook.vue'
  //This will be loaded through an API
  const links = [
    'Instagram',
    'Facebook'
  ]
  const componentMap = {
    Instagram: LinkToInstagram,
    Facebook: LinkToFacebook,
  }
</script>

<template>
  <span v-for="link of links" :key="link">
    <component :is="componentMap[link]" show-link-text="true" slug="itest" />
  </span>
</template>
```